# Find $\int^{1}_{0}x^{x}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

The answer can be in the form of two defined constants:
$$A = \frac{1}{1^1}+\frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^3} + \cdots$$
$$B = \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{4^4} + \frac{1}{6^6} + \cdots $$

I would highly appreciate it if you included your thought process in the answer itself.

---

As pointed out by [zz20s](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/213842/zz20s)
, the answer to this integral can be seen on the wikipedia page: [Sophomore's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream?wprov=sfla1) and the page accompanies a proof too

Comment: [Sophomore's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream)

Comment: $$e^{x\log x}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(x\log x)^n}{n!}$$ and $$\int_{0}^{1}(x\log x)^n\,dx = \frac{(-1)^n n!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}$$ so the answer is $A-B$.

Comment: It should be $A - 2B$, shouldn't it?

Comment: Your question is a part of:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2019859/sum-of-sum-n-geq-1-frac-ln-x-1nnn/2022761#2022761

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: there is no known closed form for $\int x^x \, \mathrm dx$.

But since we have bounds, we can use froggie's approach in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/141423/467139).

Recall that: $$\int_0^1 x^x\, \mathrm dx = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}\int_0^1x^k(\log x)^k\, \mathrm dx$$

Make the substitution $u = -\log x$

$$\int_0^1 x^x\, \mathrm dx = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}\int_0^1x^k(\log x)^k\, \mathrm dx = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\int_0^\infty e^{u(k+1)}u^k\, \mathrm du$$$$ = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\frac{1}{(k+1)^k}\int_0^\infty e^{u(k+1)}((k+1)u)^k\, \mathrm du$$

Make the substitution $t = (k+1)u$

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\frac{1}{(k+1)^k}\int_0^\infty e^tt^k\, \mathrm dt = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)!}\frac{1}{(k+1)^k}\Gamma(k+1),$$ where $\Gamma$ is the usual Gamma function. Since $\Gamma(k+1) = k!$, the final expression is $$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)^{k+1}} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^n}$$

Answer (score 1):

I have written a detailed explanation to find the integral of a general expression of the form $f(x) =x^{cx^a} $ from $0$ to $1$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2585634/how-to-show-that-int-0-infty-frac1xx-dx2/2585651#2585651).

> $$\int_{0}^{1} x^{cx^a}\, dx = 1- \frac{c}{(a+1)^2} + \frac{c^2}{(2a+1)^3} - \frac{c}{(3a+1)^4}+\ldots$$

On substituting $c =1$ and $a=1$, we get the desired result.